# Export and Import MongoDB?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I come from a bash and mysql environment.  I'm trying to get use to mongodb. I see there are different ways to export and import mongodbs.  Does anyone know the bash and mongodb equivalent of

```
bash> mysqldump -u username -p -h localhost mydatabase> mydatabase.sql

bash> mysql -u username -p -h localhost;

mysql> create database mynewdatabase; grant all privileges on mynewdatabase.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'mypass'; exit;

bash> mysql -u username -p -h localhost mynewdatabase < mydatabase.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at `mongodump` and `mongorestore` here in this tutorial in the documentation for [backup and restore tools](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/)